# Get a list of instance variable names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get a list of all instance variables of a class *without* creating an instance of that class. I have a feeling that this is not possible in Python.

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, fullname, age):
        self.firstname, self.lastname = fullname.split(' ')
        self.age = age
```

What I want to get from this is the list `['lastname', 'age', 'firstname']`.

The only way I've been able to get this is by using a temporary instance of `Person`:

```
temp = Person('Bob Jones', 27)
print vars(temp)  # {'lastname': 'Jones', 'age': 27, 'firstname': 'Bob'}
print vars(temp).keys()  # ['lastname', 'age', 'firstname']
```

The problem here is that, because `fullname.split()` is called, if I try to make an empty instance with `Person(None, None)`, an error will be raised. I'm not allowed to change `__init__` to allow this.

My first thought was to use `vars(Person).keys()`, but this gives all attributes of the `Person` type, not what an instance of `Person` would have:

```
print vars(Person).keys()
# ['__module__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__', '__init__']
```

Is there a way, without modifying the class, to do this without using `temp`?

Comment: Unless your attributes are all properties or otherwise defined on the class, you can't do this; the attributes created in `__init__` don't exist until an instance has been created.

Comment: Since we can add arbitrary attributes, there's no way to know what attributes a particular instance will have at any given moment without asking it.

Comment: "The problem here is that I have to know that Person.__init__ takes a str and an int." No. You have to know that __init__ takes an argument which has a split() method, and another one. Duck typing - define yourself a Banana class, give it a split() method, and Person.__init__ will happily take it, as long as that split() method produces two things as output

Comment: @JonKiparsky That makes sense. I edited my question so that's more accurate. Either way, that particular problem persists as there's no `None.split()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not know what attributes will be defined until it executes the `__init__` method.  In order to execute that method, you have to create an instance of the class.  Oh well :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how badly you want to know. For example, you could fork/exec a new instance of your program, instantiate the class, analyze the instance, and return your result.

You could create an object that used some of the `__magic_methods__()` to detect which, if any, of its methods were being called (such as `.split()`) and then try to guess an appropriate input type...

But can you call something that knows what the starting list of instance data will be? No.

Comment: Could there be a way to detect every time in init that `self.something  = somethingelse` is called, then build a list of everything that was assigned to?

Comment: You could override or temporarily replace the class' [`__setattr__` method.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__set__#object.__setattr__)